# Start simplex method from feasible internal point

Tags: linear-programming

I have one algorithm that generates a feasible solution to a linear programming problem. However, it is very likely that this is not a corner point. This makes it not suitable for direct use as an initial feasible solution for a bounded Simplex solver. How can I efficiently find a corner point from this solution that I can use?

Comment: You can try modifying its coordinates one by one until you get enough tight inequalities. Use the concept of slack just as in the simplex algorithm.